Programmatically enable/Disable a plugin repository
I'd like to enable or disable a repository from the plugin repository with pyqgis.
Exactly like when you're clicking on this checkbox in the plugin manager interface :

I only find a way to remove a repository but i'd rather just disable it if possible.

After some research based on this question.
I found a solution to disable a plugin repository:
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings
from pyplugin_installer import instance
from qgis.utils import updateAvailablePlugins

plugin_repository_name = 'Dépôt officiel des extensions QGIS'

settings = QSettings()

for setting in settings.allKeys():
    if setting.find('{}/enabled'.format(plugin_repository_name)) > 0:
        settings.setValue(setting, False)
updateAvailablePlugins()
instance().reloadAndExportData()

And enable it :
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings
from pyplugin_installer import instance
from qgis.utils import updateAvailablePlugins

plugin_repository_name = 'Dépôt officiel des extensions QGIS'

settings = QSettings()

for setting in settings.allKeys():
    if setting.find('{}/enabled'.format(plugin_repository_name)) > 0:
        settings.setValue(setting, True)
updateAvailablePlugins()
instance().reloadAndExportData()

